# How to do Amazon Redshift Serverless public access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to access AWS redshift serverless externally.

[image: Redshift publicly accessible]

I try to activate it by pressing this button. But even when I click the button, it is permanently off from the dashboard. I really don't know why.

[image: Redshift publicly accessible]

1. Create a public subnet
2. Open Port 5439
3. Set the router table to allow 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score -1):

I followed the directions on [Connecting to Amazon Redshift Serverless - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/serverless-connecting.html#serverless-publicly-accessible) and managed to successfully launch and connect to an Amazon Redshift Serverless instance from my own computer on the Internet.

[image: Redshift Serverless publicly accessible]

My only thought is that perhaps you did not select Public Subnets?